# ActivityIndicator not working in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, activity-indicator, react-native-push-notification

I am working with [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification). On button click, I want to delete local notification created earlier and I am able to do that using `PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({id: '123'})`. I want to show activity indicator while notifications are deleting but I am facing problem.

Here is my code. This method is triggered when button is clicked :

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Button,
    ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            spinner: false,
        }
    }

    delete = (id) => {
        this.setState({ spinner: true });
        var userid = id;
        var temp = 0;
        //I want to start my activity Indicator here
        for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            temp = Number(userid) + Number(i);
            PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({
                id: temp,
            });
        }
        this.setState({ spinner: false });
        // I want to stop my activity Indicator here
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.spinner) {

            return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <ActivityIndicator/>
                </View>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <View>
                    //code snippet
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.delete(id)}>
                        <Text>click</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't see any activity indicator

Comment: Maybe the treatment of your delete function is so fast that you can't see the activity indicator ? As setState is asynchrone.

Comment: Maybe your loop is too fast to see the ActivityIndicator. Try to define the spinner state to true to test it.

Comment: No loop is not that much fast I have checked. With or without activity Indicator, loop is taking time.

Comment: I tried with async but activity indicator is not triggering at this.setstate({spinner:true}).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here delete function is asynchronous, so, for-loop may start before `this.setState({ spinner: true });`

or `this.setState({ spinner: false });` may run immediately after `this.setState({ spinner: true });` while for-loop keeps running.

You can set your spinner variable in for-loop:

```
delete = (id) => {
        var userid = id;
        var temp = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                //start indicator here
                this.setState({ spinner: true });
            }
            temp = Number(userid) + Number(i);
            PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({
                id: temp,
            });
            if (i == 49) {
                //end indicator here
                this.setState({ spinner: false });
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `cancelLocalNotifications` method is in turn just calling a Native Bridge method, and [doesn't return anything](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/883d062716aacc55a4edd1c68078db6f206c91de/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotification.java#L205).

What this means is that you don't know when the function is complete.

My suggestion would be to fake the call, so that it looks like the app did some work.

Something along these lines should be okay:

```js
delete = (id) => {
  this.setState({ spinner: true });

  // ...

  // Wait 2 seconds and then hide the spinner
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({ spinner: false });
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: It is not working. Problem is that nothing is happening when I set spinner's state to true.

Comment: what happens if you remove the this.setState({ spinner: false })?

Comment: When I remove this.setState({ spinner: false }) activity indicator starts after completing the for loop. @WenW

Comment: That basically confirmed what @Labu was saying. The cancelLocalNotifications method is an async function that doesn't return anything, so the set spinner to false runs right after set spinner to true making the spinner not visible.

Comment: Yes but using the setTimeout() suggested activity indicator starts after all cancelLocalNotifications been deleted. I want to show activity indicator when these cancelLocalNotifications are being deleted. @WenW

Comment: Unless the cancelLocalNotfications returns a completion notification, that's not possible.

Comment: Is there an any alternative way? @WenW

Comment: the only workaround that I can think of is to create a component that checks for the notifications that you want to cancel every second until none come back, and then set the spinner to false. This is not an ideal solution tho.